# Is this broadband noise calculation correct?

Tags: noise

I came across the following paragraph from [this](https://www.thinksrs.com/downloads/pdfs/applicationnotes/AboutLIAs.pdf) application note:

[image]

I didn't quite get where the formulas come from to calculate the amplified signal and the broadband noise.

Why is signal noise not 5nV×1000 but 10nV×1000 even though the signal is 5nV where the voltage gain is 1000?

What is the generic formula they use to calculate the broadband noise here? They use:

> input_signal × sqrt(BW_amplifier) × voltage_gain

Is that formula correct? When I do the multiplication it is not 1.6mV.

Comment: You seem to have misread the quotation and to be mistaking its calculation of noise for its calculation of signal

Comment: Because the signal is 10nV and the gain is 1000. 5 nV is the noise amplitude in 1Hz BW.

Comment: I see my mistake but how about the broadband noise calculation?

Comment: 5 nV * 316 * 1000 = ...? If you don't get 1.6mV what do you get?

Comment: Perhaps the OP has assumed that sqrt (100kHz) is 10kHz?

Answer (score 0):

The sq.rt.(BW) ratio determines the SNR after the (LNA) low noise amp. Thus in order to achieve a minimum SNR for low jitter, you may need 15 to 20 dB or more (!) .

This is how to determine the required BW of the lock-in amp. Usually it is done with a much more stable VCO or VCXO or VC-OCXO according to the expected drift of the input f and tuning range of the PLL oscillator.

The other requirement may be to have a prefilter to prevent saturation after the LNA with more high gain of the next stages.

The BW of the prefilter can also be calculated by your formula to prevent saturation of the peak noise converted from RMS using a known constant (which I forgot at the moment). There may also be external noise not mentioned that must be prefiltered  and is likely much more significant than the LNA noise figure .

Answer (score 0):

> What is the generic formula they use to calculate the broadband noise
> here? They use:
>
> input_signal × sqrt(BW_amplifier) × voltage_gain
>
> Is that formula correct?

That should be input_noise_signal rather than input_signal but otherwise it is correct. I assume you're happy with the input_noise_signal x  voltage_gain part so presumably the sqrt(BW_amplifier) element is unfamiliar to you.

White noise, by definition, has equal power density at all frequencies. The noise power in some system of finite bandwidth is equal to the noise power density (i.e. the power in 1 Hz) multiplied by the bandwidth of the system.

We also note that \$Power \propto V^2\$ and hence conversely \$V \propto \sqrt{Power}\$.

So as noise power is proportional to bandwidth it follows that noise voltage is proportional to the square root of bandwidth, which is where the sqrt(BW_amplifier) term in your question comes from.

Noise power density, also known as [noise spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_spectral_density), is specified in watts/hertz (with the usual sub-multiples). Noise voltage spectral density is specified in volts/√hertz, as in your question.

> When I do the multiplication it is not 1.6mV.

It is for me so try again including \$\sqrt{100 kHz}\$.